# Retrieval protein definition from accession ID

Tags: proteins, phylogenetics, uniprot, identifiers

I have a list of protein accessions:

```
XP_025107904.1
PVD22034.1
AJA37836.1
```

How can I obtain the definition of the protein, and the related organism?

Output:

```
XP_025107904.1  receptor-type tyrosine-protein phosphatase kappa-like isoform X2  Pomacea canaliculata
```

Thanks for the help,

Marco

Comment: I solved with a Python script (through biopython):                                                
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO                                                                                           
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein", id= input_file, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "genbank"):
        print(seq_record.description + "\t" +  seq_record.id)

Comment: great! Could you please post your script as an answer and accept it so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @Marco could you please consider upvoting/accepting the answer. It does help with site stats and its only fair to terdon's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Entrez API. For example, using the three identifiers from your example, you can do:

```
curl "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=protein&id=XP_025107904.1,PVD22034.1,AJA37836.1" > file.xml
```

This will bring an XML file with the following contents:

```
$ cat file.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE eSummaryResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD esummary v1 20041029//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20041029/esummary-v1.dtd">
<eSummaryResult>
<DocSum>
    <Id>1397721498</Id>
    <Item Name="Caption" Type="String">XP_025107904</Item>
    <Item Name="Title" Type="String">receptor-type tyrosine-protein phosphatase kappa-like isoform X2 [Pomacea canaliculata]</Item>
    <Item Name="Extra" Type="String">gi|1397721498|ref|XP_025107904.1|[1397721498]</Item>
    <Item Name="Gi" Type="Integer">1397721498</Item>
    <Item Name="CreateDate" Type="String">2018/06/07</Item>
    <Item Name="UpdateDate" Type="String">2018/06/07</Item>
    <Item Name="Flags" Type="Integer">512</Item>
    <Item Name="TaxId" Type="Integer">400727</Item>
    <Item Name="Length" Type="Integer">1271</Item>
    <Item Name="Status" Type="String">live</Item>
    <Item Name="ReplacedBy" Type="String"></Item>
    <Item Name="Comment" Type="String"><![CDATA[  ]]></Item>
    <Item Name="AccessionVersion" Type="String">XP_025107904.1</Item>
</DocSum>

<DocSum>
    <Id>1383748625</Id>
    <Item Name="Caption" Type="String">PVD22034</Item>
    <Item Name="Title" Type="String">hypothetical protein C0Q70_17837 [Pomacea canaliculata]</Item>
    <Item Name="Extra" Type="String">gi|1383748625|gb|PVD22034.1||gnl|WGS:PZQS|C0Q70_17837[1383748625]</Item>
    <Item Name="Gi" Type="Integer">1383748625</Item>
    <Item Name="CreateDate" Type="String">2018/04/26</Item>
    <Item Name="UpdateDate" Type="String">2018/04/26</Item>
    <Item Name="Flags" Type="Integer">0</Item>
    <Item Name="TaxId" Type="Integer">400727</Item>
    <Item Name="Length" Type="Integer">602</Item>
    <Item Name="Status" Type="String">live</Item>
    <Item Name="ReplacedBy" Type="String"></Item>
    <Item Name="Comment" Type="String"><![CDATA[  ]]></Item>
    <Item Name="AccessionVersion" Type="String">PVD22034.1</Item>
</DocSum>

<DocSum>
    <Id>735659541</Id>
    <Item Name="Caption" Type="String">AJA37836</Item>
    <Item Name="Title" Type="String">fucolectin-related molecule [Littorina littorea]</Item>
    <Item Name="Extra" Type="String">gi|735659541|gb|AJA37836.1|[735659541]</Item>
    <Item Name="Gi" Type="Integer">735659541</Item>
    <Item Name="CreateDate" Type="String">2014/12/25</Item>
    <Item Name="UpdateDate" Type="String">2014/12/25</Item>
    <Item Name="Flags" Type="Integer">0</Item>
    <Item Name="TaxId" Type="Integer">31216</Item>
    <Item Name="Length" Type="Integer">722</Item>
    <Item Name="Status" Type="String">live</Item>
    <Item Name="ReplacedBy" Type="String"></Item>
    <Item Name="Comment" Type="String"><![CDATA[  ]]></Item>
    <Item Name="AccessionVersion" Type="String">AJA37836.1</Item>
</DocSum>

</eSummaryResult>
```

You can now parse this in your favorite language/parser and get the information you need. I... am not too good with XML so my attempts with `xmllint` failed, but here's a naive awk approach:

```
$ awk -F'[][><]' '{ if(/Name="Title"/){desc=$3; spc=$4}else if(/Name="AccessionVersion"/){name=$3} if($0=="</DocSum>"){print name,desc,spc; name=""; desc=""; spc=""}}' file.xml 
XP_025107904.1 receptor-type tyrosine-protein phosphatase kappa-like isoform X2  Pomacea canaliculata
PVD22034.1 hypothetical protein C0Q70_17837  Pomacea canaliculata
AJA37836.1 fucolectin-related molecule  Littorina littorea
```

I stress that this is a very bad idea and you should use a proper XML parser, but it might work...